# Changing the value of a variable from the scope of the function

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I am studying and trying to understand how scope works in javascript. My main problem is that when I change the value of a variable using a function, it gives me not what I want. I expect to receive in console last scope, like in function `visible_scope_1();`. but as for the last function visible_scope_3(), I just wanted to do it a little differently, but I also got a failure. In general, you may not pay attention to the last function.

```js
// Very well ! So and want ...
// only do with help at scope visible functions ...
function visible_scope_1() {
    var message = "local scope";
    message = "changed local scope";
    message = "last scope";
    return message;
}

// Wrong : show all resuls ...
function visible_scope_2 () {
    var message = "local scope";
    var a1 = function() {
        console.log(message = "inside local scope");
        var b2 = function () {
            console.log(message = "deeper scope");
            var c3 = function () {

                // I want to get the result from this scope. Is it possible?
                console.log(message = "last scope");
            }; c3();
        }; b2();
    }; a1();
}

// Wrong : show undefined
function visible_scope_3 () {
    message = "local scope";
    var a1 = function() {
        message = "inside local scope";
        return message;
        var b2 = function () {
            message = "deeper scope";
            return message;
            var c3 = function () {
                // i expect to show in console "last scope"
                message = "last scope";
                return message;
            }; c3();
        }; b2();
    }; a1();
}
```

Comment: Remove the `console.log` statements in `visible_scope_2` (but keep the assignment, i.e. `console.log(message = ...) -> message = ...`) and add `return message;` to `visible_scope_2` at the very end. `visible_scope_3` doesn't work as is because you are returning from the `a1` function before you even call `b2`.

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll take a look now ...

Comment: Probably i make something wrong. I made how you had said but in console showing undefined in function visible_scope_2(); But as for the visible area 3 (); you are probably right, because it shows in the console and stops, and on others returns don't look. (I hope I said correctly.)

Comment: Oh sorry it works.

Comment: I'm a little surprised, thank you buddy for help. :)